# Can you use dot notation when referring to classes in relation to other classes in OCL?

Tags: uml, class-diagram, ocl

For example, let's say I have a situation like this

[image]

Can I write an OCL expression that counts how many students a school has, such as:

```
School.students->count()
```

?

Or would it be incorrect? And in that case, how would I count the number of students?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the dot is the correct OCL syntax, here.

This is explained in the OCL specifications, section 7.4.10 on navigation operators:

> The "." navigation operator supports navigation from an object using a property or operation.
> The "->" navigation operator supports navigation from a collection using a property, operation or iteration.

Furthermore,  section 7.5.3 on navigation of properties explain that:

> Starting from a specific object, we can navigate an association on the class diagram to refer to other objects and their properties. To do so, we navigate the association by using the opposite association-end:
> `object.associationEndName`
> The value of this expression is the set of objects on the other side of the `associationEndName` association.

There is just one issue here: `students` is not formally defined. In principle you should use the role name indicated at the association end (next to the `*`), and if no such role is given in the class diagram, you should use the class name instead, so `student`.

Not related: `count()` is used with an argument regarding the objects that have to be counted in the set.  If you mean the number of students associated with a given school, you should use `->size()`

Comment: Use of the class name would be "Student" not "student", but failure to provide a navigable role name is a UML WFR violation; Property is a NamedElement that must have a name? It is certainly not within the OCL's remit; inference of missing role names is only specified for unnavigable opposites where there is no Property.

Comment: count(x) is an operation with an argument identifying the occurrences of x to be counted. The more powerful iteration can be emulated by ->select(...)->size().

Comment: @EdWillink good points!  On the capitalisation, you are right from the OCL perspective. However there are conflicts between the specs.  I stick to this UML rule:  "*If an association end is unlabeled, the default name for that end is the name of the class to which the end is attached, modified such that the first letter is a lowercase letter*". -

Comment: OCL is tolerant about this when it is stated that: "*If no explicit name is available an implicit name is taken from the name of the class to which the end is attached*", since it is a non-normative note: "*Note to tool vendors; this is a non-normative change from OCL 2.2, where the UML style guidance of converting the first letter of the implicit name to lowercase was endorsed. The normative text has never defined how implicit names are obtained. Tool vendors may wish to provide backward/forward compatibility warnings for this change.*"

Comment: Indeed. Nice to see someone paying close attention to my words; the best I could do to phase out an unwise UMLism without breaking anything.